# Do iPhones contain a cryptographically secure authentication mechanism?

Tags: authentication, iphone, trust

Firstly is it true that iPhones have a trusted execution environment that can be used to protect asymmetric key pairs for which the private portion of the key cannot be exported by any means other than hardware attack (for example side channel) or a defeat of the trusted execution environment's code authentication mechanism?

Assuming this is true does Apple use this TEE key pair during manufacturing to establish a chain of trust via certificates? This would be accomplished for example by attaching newly built iPhones in the factory to computer connected to an HSM for the purposes of signing a CSR generated on the iPhone to produce a certificate chain with an Apple device-specific root certificate.

Furthermore if this is the case does the iPhone provide the API which would make it possible for third party application to initiate a challenge-response using the keypair secured by the TEE and thus establish a mutually authenticated connection to an Apple iPhone?